# Extracting heading and strong tag with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am looking to extract the text string from a heading inside a `div` and the text within `<strong>` tags with BeautifulSoup.

I can get the heading with `soup.h1` but I would like to get the `h1` that is specifically within the div `<div class="site-content">`

HTML:

`<div class="site-content"><h1>Here is the title<strong>( And a bit more! )</strong></h1></div>`

So I would like to get `Here is the title` and `( And a bit more! )`
Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you maybe accept the answer to mark the question as resolved if it was helpful? This will help other users too.

Answer (score 2):

you can use find `attrs` parameter, like:

```
soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'site-content'}).h1
```

EDIT: to get direct text only

```
for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'site-content'}):
    print ''.join([x for x in div.h1.contents \
                                 if isinstance(x, bs4.element.NavigableString)])
```

life is easier with [lxml and xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html):

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> root = html.parse('x.html')
>>> print root.xpath('//div[@class="site-content"]/h1/text()')
['Here is the title']
>>> print root.xpath('//div[@class="site-content"]/h1//text()')
['Here is the title', '( And a bit more! )']
>>> print root.xpath('//div[@class="site-content"]/h1/strong/text()')
['( And a bit more! )']
```

Comment: Thanks, had this code like this previously, do you know how I could get the text within `<strong></strong>`?

Comment: Is there any way with `soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'site-content'}).h1` of getting the just the first part of `h1` without the `<strong>`? thanks

Comment: Adding `recursive=False` to soup arguments gives the error `meta_file = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'site-content'}, recursive=False).h1.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'h1'`

Comment: @DanielPilch to get text inside `<strong>`, you may actually do `soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'site-content'}).h1.strong`

Answer (score -1):

The code to to extract the text string from a heading inside a div and the text within  tags with BeautifulSoup.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = """<div class="site-content"><h1>Here is the title<strong>( And a bit more! )</strong></h1>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
>>> reqText = soup.find('h1').text
>>> print(reqText)
'Here is the title( And a bit more! )'
>>> reqText1 = soup.find('strong').text
>>> print(reqText1)
'( And a bit more! )'
```

or

```
>>> data = """<div class="site-content"><h1>Here is the title<strong>( And a bit more! )</strong></h1>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
>>> soup.find('strong').text
'( And a bit more! )'
>>> reqText1 = soup.find('h1')
>>> for i in reqText1:
...    p_tag = soup.h1
...    s_tag = soup.strong
...    s_tag.decompose()
...    p_tag.get_text()
...
'Here is the title'
```